# How do I write a function that tests if a positive integer n can be written as sum of two squared integers, i. e. n = i^2 +j^2 with i; j 2 N>0

Tags: r, integer, control-flow

I've been cracking my head trying to solve this problem but so far I haven't been able to do it. How could I write this code in R?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I can't add a comment but I guess this wikipedia article can really help you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

basically, you should decompose n to its primes and then check:

> An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if its prime decomposition contains no term p^k, where prime p = 3 mod 4 and k is odd.

Comment: if someone can turn this into a comment i'd be grateful... thanks!

Comment: why do you want this to be a comment ? For me it's quite a valid answer (unless someone post clear R code) and answers are IMHO > comments

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can build a user function `f` like below

```
f <- function(n) {
  p <- seq(floor(sqrt(n - 1)))
  q <- sqrt(n - p**2)
  idx <- q == floor(q)
  data.frame(A = p[idx], B = q[idx])
}
```

such that

```
> f(9)
[1] A B
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

> f(100)
  A B
1 6 8
2 8 6

> f(500)
   A  B
1  4 22
2 10 20
3 20 10
4 22  4

> f(1000)
   A  B
1 10 30
2 18 26
3 26 18
4 30 10
```

where `f(9)` giving an empty data frame means that `9` cannot be decomposed as the sum of two squared integers.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the theorem mentioned by Blop

```
library(gmp)
library(data.table)

is_sum_two_squared_ints <- function(x){
  
  factor <- gmp::factorize(x)
  factor_mod4 <- gmp::mod.bigz(factor, 4)
  
  # converting from Big Integer to integer, assuming your number isn't too big
  dt <- data.table(factor = as.integer(factor), factor_mod4 = as.integer(factor_mod4))
  
  n_meets_criteria <- 
    dt[, .N, .(factor, factor_mod4)][factor_mod4 == 3 & N %% 2 == 1, .N]
  
  return(n_meets_criteria == 0)

}


is_sum_two_squared_ints(25)
# [1] TRUE
is_sum_two_squared_ints(3)
# [1] FALSE
is_sum_two_squared_ints(220)
# [1] FALSE
is_sum_two_squared_ints(116)
# [1] TRUE
```